# How to add logo and the menu on the image in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website which contain logo and the menu. the case is i want to add those items on the top of page and on the slider like this first image. logo is transparent image. so it want to display slider image as the background of the slider as second image.

I used bootstrap 3 here.

This is the structure of html.

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        //logo image
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"">                 
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav>                                          
    </div>

    </div>
</header>
<div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
       //slider
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

Logo css -

```
.banner-img {
overflow: visible;
z-index: 10000;
float: left;
position: absolute;
}
```

Menu css -

```
.menu {
background: #f7f6f0;
padding: 0;
float: right;
width: 100%;
}
```

Image 01

[image: Image 01]

[image: Image 02]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: what's your current css?

Comment: @LorDex i added css now

Comment: you could use negative margin-top for your `container-fluid` to drag it under the logo.

Comment: @Wavemaster is is negative margin?

Comment: As you don't provide a fiddle or a live example I have to guess a solution.  Negative **`margin-top`** let you push the element to the top and over other elements, who are in the way.  As you set `z-index` for your logo, it will slide under the logo.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="http://skymaiden.com/placeholder.php" alt="" />
</div>
<nav>Menu</nav>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    z-index-999;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
nav {
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    background:green;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:right;
}
#slider {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:pink;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqx6txv2/)

Answer (score 0):

just add the css z-index for logo and also change col-md-3 to col-mod-10